# Can't load sencha touch index in Android using PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I follow the guide in [**http://phonegap.com/start#android**](http://phonegap.com/start#android) to load my **app.js** from **Sencha Touch**.

This is my **index.html**:

```
<head>
    <title>Getting Started</title>

    <!-- Sencha Touch -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/touch/resources/css/sencha-touch.css" type="text/css"></link>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/touch/builds/sencha-touch-all.js"></script>

    <!-- Application -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/touch/resources/css/app.css" type="text/css"></link>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/www/app.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="assets/www/phonegap-1.4.1.js">
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
```

The src links for the libs it's correct. what i can do to load my app.js in android device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PhoneGap, all of your files and directories should be in the assets/www directory and referenced from there.  Thus, with your index.html in assets/www it should refer to app.js and phonegap-1.4.1 without any prefaced directories:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js">
```